# Ocaml: Unbound module Array

Tags: ocaml

Why doesn't work?

```
let data = [| 1; 2; 3; 4; |] in
  let len = Array.length data in
    for i = 0 to len do
      Printf.printf "%d\n" i
    done
```

ocamlc array.ml -c array.byte 
Displays an error is Unbound module Array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might come from the name of your source code : array.ml
which collapse with the name of the module you wish to use.

Just change the name of your file to sth else, and you should compile succesfully.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have been suffering from this problem all morning